# how to change the source value of the NLog eventlog target

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

Is there any possibility to change the source name of NLog.config dynamically if yes can any one please help me.

```
<targets>
<target xsi:type="EventLog" name="eventlog" layout="${callsite}:${message}" log="Application" **source="MyAwesomeSolution"**/>
```

this is the source name which i wanna change with parameters coming from other method to NLog.Config file.
**source="MyAwesomeSolution"**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any possibility to change the source dynamically during runtime @WahidBitar

Answer (score 1):

You can use any predefined variable or your custom field in the source field.

e.g. `source="${event-properties:item=customName}"`

and in your code, you can fill this value

```
logger.Info("this event is coming from may {customName}", "my app");
```

or you can use

```
logger.SetProperty("customName", "my app");
```

or even

```
logger.WithProperty("customName", "my app").Info("test message");
```

for more details check out the documentation

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer#example

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventLog-target

Comment: Not Working...Actually nothing is coming

Comment: I guess you didn't create the sources as explained in the second link that I have shared

Comment: When installing/uninstalling, the event source is only created/removed when the source doesn't contain layout renderers.

When installing, the event source can only be created when run as an Administrator. Alternatively a simple PowerShell command to create this source is shown below (run PowerShell as Administrator). `New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "MySourceName"`

Comment: the message is coming but the thing is the source Name is not changing based on the selected instance @Wahid Bitar

Comment: This looks correct :) (upvoted it). Also there are other ways to set the context, e.g. the GDC. See all options here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context